# youtube iframe height issue on ios7 ipad

Tags: ios7, html5-video, mobile-safari, youtube-iframe-api

I'm can't get youtube videos to display with the correct height on iOS 7.1, ipad mini, even in the most simple test case. Here's an iframe embed taken directly from the youtube site:

```
<iframe width="300" height="169" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/8vZqjg-9gTg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

When displayed on my ipad min (ios7.1), the height is not calculated correctly. It appears as though the control bar might have something to do with it... the height seems to be off by the height of the control bar (or close to it).

Here's a test page: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tnIsC/